# Could we use the Lagrange multiplier to solve Basis pursuit?

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Since the basis pursuit problem is of the type: $\min_{\alpha} \parallel \alpha\parallel s.t\ y=X\alpha$.
Shouldn't we be able to solve it using the Lagrange multiplier? Why is that an option that I never see in documentations?

Thanks !

Edit : https://www.hindawi.com/journals/mpe/2022/8711843/#EEq5 gives me the following solution $diag(|\alpha|) X^T (A\ diag(|\alpha|)\ A^T)^{-1}y$ where $diag(u)$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal is taken from vector u. Is that something accurate ?

Comment: This is definitely used, see these slides https://book-wright-ma.github.io/Lecture-Slides/Lecture_14.pdf

Comment: @mordecaiiwazuki Thanks ! Those slides are saying that the 'classical' Lagragian doesn't work but the augmented does, right ? And it doesn't give me a generic solution to basis pursuit...

Comment: You cannot find a closed form solution to basis pursuit, even using Lagrange multipliers. When they say something works or doesn't work, they mean with respect to practice. Mathematically, everything works for Lagrangian methods (convergence) although in practice it's not the most efficient/stable/etc.